# Kurento Many to Many Recording Blank Videos

Tags: java, webrtc, kurento

I'm trying to work off code that was written for the Many-To-Many demo, while using the One-to-One w/ Recording demo as reference. I've add the following code to UserSession.java constructor:

```
  public static final String RECORDING_PATH = "file:///recordings/";
  public static final String RECORDING_EXT = ".webm";

  public UserSession(final String name, String roomName, final WebSocketSession session, MediaPipeline pipeline) {
    this.pipeline = pipeline;
    this.name = name;
    this.session = session;
    this.roomName = roomName;

    this.outgoingMedia = new WebRtcEndpoint.Builder(pipeline).build();
    this.recorder = new RecorderEndpoint.Builder(pipeline, RECORDING_PATH + roomName + '_' + name + RECORDING_EXT).build();

    this.isRecording = false;
```

And I've added this to to bottom of the *getEndpointForUser* method after incoming media is connected to the session's peer:

```
sender.getOutgoingWebRtcPeer().connect(incoming);
sender.getOutgoingWebRtcPeer().connect(this.recorder);
```

I'm triggering record and stop record manually from the browser with socket calls, but the video files are always empty (0kb). The correct number of videos are created for each session they just don't have any data. Does anyone have any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is **VERY IMPORTANT** that the RecorderEndpoint is aware of what media container constraint profile is being used. My problem was that I had audio turned off on the front end media constraints while developing (it's annoying). The RecorderEndpoint needs to be aware of this by you passing in the correct MediaProfileSpecType.

```
this.recorder = new RecorderEndpoint.Builder(pipeline, RECORDING_PATH + roomName + '_' + name + RECORDING_EXT)
  .withMediaProfile(MediaProfileSpecType.WEBM)
  .build();
```

Simply turning back on audio on the front end fixed it, but you can also reference code contained in the other tutorials where the Kurento team is connecting the RecorderEndpoint according to some sort of media constraint container logic, which you will likely need in a production app for people who have webcam issues where either audio or video is not coming through.